# Why do I have this error when using pyplot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

Ok, now this is just an example code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot   

time = [0, 1, 2, 3]
position = [0, 100, 200, 300]

pyplot.plot(time, position)
pyplot.xlabel('Time (hr)')
pyplot.ylabel('Position (km)')
```

And the output is this:

```
= RESTART: C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/pyplot_test.py
```

Where `C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/pyplot_test.py` is the path file of this example code. Any help?

Windows 10
Python 3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes, silly me, I forgot `pyplot.show()`. Now it works.